# SQL statement with group by - list of passengers

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

with the following statement I am trying to select the list of passengers with their total weight of luggage. I keep receiving this error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=979]. If I add all the expressions in the select clause, I get rid of the error, however the statement lists passengers multiple times if they have more than just one item of luggage.

Any idea how to fix it? Thank you.

```
select f.flugnummer, p.nachname, pl.sitzplatznummer, l.bezeichnung, r.reisepassnr, sum(g.gewicht) as Luggage
from passagierliste pl join flug f on f.flugID = pl.flugID
    join gepaeck g on pl.personID = g.personID
    join person p on pl.personID = p.personID
    join reisepass r on p.personID = r.personID
    join land l on r.landID = l.landID
    group by nachname;
```

Comment: You have a zillion unaggregated columns in the `select`.  Either remove them from the `select` or add them to the `group by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query,

```
select f.flugnummer, p.nachname, pl.sitzplatznummer, l.bezeichnung, r.reisepassnr, 
sum(g.gewicht) as Luggage
from passagierliste pl join flug f on f.flugID = pl.flugID
join gepaeck g on pl.personID = g.personID
join person p on pl.personID = p.personID
join reisepass r on p.personID = r.personID
join land l on r.landID = l.landID
group by f.flugnummer, p.nachname, pl.sitzplatznummer, l.bezeichnung, r.reisepassnr;
```

Whenever you are aggregating, you have to use all the columns you select in group by

Comment: Tips for posting here: (a) line breaks are very rarely needed, and should certainly not be added at the top of every post; (b) please don't add salutations, greetings, thanks and signatures - Stack Overflow is not a chatroom; (c) spell-check your work, most browsers have an English spell-checker available in the editor; (d) use appropriate punctuation. Remember that your work is not just for the question author, but for readers many years into the future.

Comment: @halfer, thank you for your kind explanation. Will follow as you suggested, further.